# How do I give custom folder names to the folders for ffmpeg HLS export?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm making a function to transcode some videos which will be saved in 480p and 360p variants in two different folders through FFMPEG

this is the command

```
"ffmpeg -i vid.mp4 " \
"-filter_complex " \
"[0:v]split=2[v2][v3];" \
"[v2]scale=720:-2[v2out]; [v3]scale=360:-2[v3out] " \
"-map [v2out] -c:v:0 libx265 -sc_threshold 0 -crf:v:1 30 -level:v:0 3.0 -keyint_min:v:0 48 -g:v:0 48 "\
"-map [v3out] -c:v:1 libx265 -sc_threshold 0 -crf:v:2 30 -level:v:1 3.0 -keyint_min:v:1 48 -g:v:1 48 "\
"-map a:0 -c:a:0 aac -b:a:0 96k -ac:a:0 2 "\
"-map a:0 -c:a:1 aac -b:a:1 48k -ac:a:1 2 "\
"-f hls "\
"-hls_time 6 "\
"-hls_list_size 0 "\
"-hls_segment_filename v%v/segment_%d.ts " \
"-master_pl_name master.m3u8 "\
"-var_stream_map "v:0,a:0 v:1,a:1" v%v/stream.m3u8"
```

however, this generates the folders as **v0,v1** I need the names to be **360p and 480p** rather than **v0 and v1**, is there any way I can map that while running the command rather than editing the folder names and master playlist after the command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide names in `-var_stream_map`:

```
ffmpeg -i vid.mp4 \
-filter_complex "[0:v]split=2[v2][v3];[v2]scale=720:-2[v2out];[v3]scale=360:-2[v3out]" \
-map "[v2out]" -c:v:0 libx265 -sc_threshold 0 -crf:v:1 30 -level:v:0 3.0 -keyint_min:v:0 48 -g:v:0 48 \
-map "[v3out]" -c:v:1 libx265 -sc_threshold 0 -crf:v:2 30 -level:v:1 3.0 -keyint_min:v:1 48 -g:v:1 48 \
-map a:0 -c:a:0 aac -b:a:0 96k -ac:a:0 2 \
-map a:0 -c:a:1 aac -b:a:1 48k -ac:a:1 2 \
-f hls \
-hls_time 6 \
-hls_list_size 0 \
-hls_segment_filename "v%v/segment_%d.ts" \
-master_pl_name master.m3u8 \
-var_stream_map "v:0,a:0,name:480p v:1,a:1,name:360p" v%v/stream.m3u8
```

Refer to [FFmpeg segment muxer documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#hls-2).